# Enabling audit in Oracle

Tags: oracle-12c, audit

I have a table 'class' owned by the schema 'test' and I need to audit all operations on the particular table.

`audit INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE ON test.class` --  will this be sufficient to do the trick?

Should I enable any other kind of Fine grained auditing to capture all the details.

Oracle12c/RHEL - I have set audit trail to DB. And sys operations to true.

Inputs needed here

Comment: That'll do, but things have changed significantly in 12c. This is worth a read: https://blogs.oracle.com/imc/entry/oracle_database_12c_new_unified

Comment: I do see logs getting logged but Im not able to see the sql_text for the audit which caused the insert on the table. SQL_TEXT is showing blank.

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm late for party, but someone else with similiar issue may find it useful so anyways: I would say that you don't have AUDIT_TRAIL set to DB,EXTENDED but perhaps only to DB or something.

If you want SQLTEXT to be populated it is mandatory to have AUDIT_TRAIL set to DB,EXTENDED.

Check your current AUDIT_TRAIL status:

```
select * from v$parameter where name like '%trail%';
```

If it's not set to DB,EXTENDED, you set it with the following command:

```
alter system set audit_trail=db,extended scope=spfile;
```

Bear in mind that after setting it to DB,EXTENDED, you have to restart your instance for changes to take effect.

Afterwards after each audit record your SQLTEXT in SYS.AUD$ will also be populated.

From Oracle's documentation you will see more:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/initparams016.htm#REFRN10006